# Github error on git push: error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read:

Tags: git, github, git-push

When tried to push a project on my machine to new repo in github.The error given below is thrown

```
$ git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 420, done.
Counting objects: 100% (420/420), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (284/284), done.
Writing objects: 100% (420/420), 47.56 MiB | 233.00 MiB/s, done.
Total 420 (delta 114), reused 420 (delta 114), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```